# Swift: set @IBOutlet static

Tags: swift, static, iboutlet

I want change `@IBOutlet` text value from another class

How i can set `@IBOutlet` to static ?

Below code not work:

```
@IBOutlet internal static var boxGender: UIView!
```

Comment: It might be *XY problem* here; Why would you declare an outlet as static? what's the reason behind it?

Comment: If you just want to change value from another class use any : Delegates, Notifications or Callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a static value of your controller and get all values from them. But this is not a right way to reach your outlets. You should pass your controller to other class instance.

```
class Test: UIViewController {
    var boxGender: UIView!
    static var instance: Test?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Test.instance = self
    }
}
Test.instance?.boxGender
```

Answer (score 1):

An IBOutlet cannot be static. (The compiler will give the error `Only instance properties can be declared @IBOutlet`)

```
 class SomeViewWithALabel: UIView {        
        @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!    
        // ... methods and properties                
 }


 class MyController: UIViewController {        
        @IBOutlet weak var someViewWithALabel: SomeViewWithALabel!    

        //...

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
             super.viewWillAppear(animated)
             someViewWithALabel?.myLabel.text == "Custom text"
        }   
 }
```